# Doctrine2 One-To-Many with multiple fields

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, one-to-many

Is there a way to add a relationship based on two fields?

For example, I have a `Files` table/Entity that has a string field called `type` and a integer field called `type_id`.  I need to have a relationship on my `Book` Entity that joins where `type = 'BOOK'` and `type_id = id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how to do multiple join here:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#jointable

You can also join the entity with field type_id and discriminate in the query the attr type:

```
/*
* @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Files")
* @JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $file;
```

And do in QueryBuilder:

```
->join('file.books', 'books', 'WITH', 'books.type = "BOOK"')
```

I hope this help you